# Unable to run torch using remote access

Tags: ssh, remote-access, torch

I have torch installed on a server. I am able to run torch and execute files using `th`. However when I remote login using ssh and run `th`, it says `th: command not found`. I am unable to install anything while remote logging in too. Is it possible that by remote logging in I don't have the same path causing me to have a different profile and PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to by running `bash`. By default, SSH doesn't open a bash terminal for me. The last line of `bashrc`   activates the torch bin which one can execute without running `bash`.